# Create Image Button at run time in Listview

Tags: android, listview, imagebutton

I have List View which display data from database.
Now i want to create image button in that list view with each Row and that image button use for delete row which i m select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ListViews we have adapter wich provide ui elements. In initView or getView method you can change view for needed position. Helpful for you will be methods of adapter getCount or getPosition.

Comment: Thanks dear, if you have sample code for that. plz sent to me.